# Vue Apollo query single item with ID

Tags: vue.js, graphql, typeerror, vue-apollo

I am trying to query a single product using Vue Apollo but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. In the console I get the following error:  `Observable.js?a7b2:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'product' of undefined`

**Query:**

```
export const getProduct = gql`
  query getProduct ($productId: ID!) {
    product (where: {id: $productId}) {
      id
      title
      description
      price
      productDetails {
        html
      }
      productAssets {
        id
        url
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

**Component:**

```
apollo: {
  $loadingKey: 'loading',
  products: {
    query: getProduct,
    variables: {
      $productId: 'ABC123',
    },
    result ({data}) {
      this.loading = false;
      this.product = data.product;
      this.assets = data.assets;
    },
    error () {
      this.error = true;
      this.sentryError = error;
    },
  },
},
```

If I however hard code the ID in, it works.

```
export const product = gql`
  query getProduct ($product: ID!) {
    product (where: {id: "ABC123"}) {
      id
      title
      description
      price
      productDetails {
        html
      }
      productAssets {
        id
        url
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I don't see what I am missing, any help will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: `variables: { productId: 'ABC123' }`, ?

Answer (score 1):

First, Arguments can be required. You set `$product: ID!` (by `!`) to be required.

`Playground` - options to run the query:

### 1. QUERY by "hard code"

> "If I however hard code the ID in, it works"

This is the first way (You declare the argument manually in your Query).

### 2. "QUERY VARIABLES" tab

Click on [QUERY VARIABLES] and pass the vars Variables in **JSON** format.

[image]

**graphql-variables Extra reading:**

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/introduction-to-graphql-variables-and-complex-operations-2065d8cd2377

### Vue -  Query with parameters:

```
// Apollo-specific options
apollo: {
  // Query with parameters
  ping: {
    // gql query
    query: gql`query PingMessage($message: String!) {
      ping(message: $message)
    }`,
    // Static parameters
    variables: {
      message: 'Meow',
    },
  },
},
```

https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/queries.html#query-with-parameters